# Compile error (Argument not optional) creating a rule

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to write a VBA script that will add the domains of all selected emails to the blocked senders list in Outlook.

I am receiving an error:

> Compile error:
> Argument not optional.

on

```
Set blockedSendersRule = blockedSenders.Create("Blocked Domains")
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAbHt.png)

```vb
Sub AddDomainsToBlockedSendersList()
    Dim olSelection As Selection
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim blockedSenders As Outlook.Rules
    Dim blockedSendersRule As Outlook.Rule
    Dim domainList As Collection
    Dim domain As String
    Dim msg As String
    
    ' Initialize Outlook objects
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set blockedSenders = olNamespace.DefaultStore.GetRules()
    Set domainList = New Collection
    
    ' Get selected emails
    Set olSelection = olApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    
    ' Loop through selected emails
    For Each olItem In olSelection
        If olItem.Class = olMail Then
            domain = GetDomainFromEmail(olItem.SenderEmailAddress)
            If Not IsDuplicate(domain, domainList) Then
                domainList.Add domain
            End If
        End If
    Next olItem
    
    ' Add domains to blocked senders list
    If domainList.Count > 0 Then
        Set blockedSendersRule = blockedSenders.Create("Blocked Domains")
        
        For Each domain In domainList
            blockedSendersRule.Conditions.From.Recipients.Add domain
        Next domain
        
        blockedSendersRule.Enabled = True
        blockedSenders.Save
        msg = "Domains added to the Blocked Senders list."
    Else
        msg = "No valid domains found in selected emails."
    End If
    
    ' Display a message box
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Add Domains to Blocked Senders List"
End Sub

Function GetDomainFromEmail(email As String) As String
    Dim parts() As String
    parts = Split(email, "@")
    If UBound(parts) = 1 Then
        GetDomainFromEmail = parts(1)
    Else
        GetDomainFromEmail = ""
    End If
End Function

Function IsDuplicate(domain As String, domainList As Collection) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    domainList.Add domain, CStr(domain)
    IsDuplicate = (Err.Number = 457) ' 457 = "Key is already associated with an element of this collection"
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

---

Adding `olRuleReceive` fixed this line.

Comment: [`Rules.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.rules.create) has two required parameters.

Comment: Thanks so much - this fixed this line but then I was receiving another compile error (For Each control variable must be Variant or Object) for the below line where domain is declared as String:


For Each domain In domainList


If I then declare domain as Object it throws the error ByRef argument type mismatch on line:


If Not IsDuplicate(domain, domainList) Then

Answer (score 0):

As per @BigBen's comment, `Rules.Create` must be passed two arguments, the name of the rule and the type of the rule, which in your case is likely `olRuleReceive` making the relevant line `Set blockedSendersRule = blockedSenders.Create("Blocked Domains", olRuleReceive)`. See the MS Docs here [Rules.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.rules.create) and here [OlRuleType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olruletype)